# Why in Python 1%2>>>1 or 5%6>>>5

Tags: python, modulo

If `%` should return the remainder, why then

```
>>>1%2
1
>>>5%6
5
```

when

```
>>>1/2
0.5
>>>5/6
0.83(3)
```

?

Comment: You confuse "remainder" with "fraction".

Comment: Please edit your question an remove the false statements "1%2 returns 0.5" and "5%6 returns 0.8333.."

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the mathematical definition of modulo which is:

```
x= quotient(x//y) * y + modulo(x%y)
```

In your examples quotient is zero which results to:

```
5 = 0 * 6 + modulo(5%6) => modulo(5%6) = 5

1 = 0 * 2 + modulo(1%2) => modulo(1%2) = 1
```